# What does the union and intersection of a single sequence of real number mean?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I read measure_theory by Paul R-Halmos, part of number 7 prerequisite concept of reading this book is:

"The supremum and infimum of a sequence {$x_n$} of real numbers are denoted by

$\bigcup_{i =1}^\infty x_i$ and $\bigcap_{i =1}^\infty x_i$."

Why would a union or intersection of a real number sequence exist? For example, number 2 and 9, what does '$2\bigcup9$' mean?

I only understand union and intersection between sets, thanks for paying attention for my question.

Comment: @Daphna, Thank you for helping edit my formula

Comment: @David K, thank you, I think there's no detail definition of real number, it's just the second page of the book,

Comment: @DavidK, thanks, I will search Dedekind cuts.

Answer (score 1):

Just before that on the same page, Halmos defines
$$
 x \cup y = \max\{x,y\}\\
  x \cap y = \min\{x,y\}
$$
That will explain what you want to know.  *There is need to mention Dedekind cuts.*

**Note:**  This notation, perhaps common in 1950, is no longer common.  Nowadays we might define instead
$$
 x \vee y = \max\{x,y\}\\ x \wedge y = \min\{x,y\}
$$

Comment: Thank you, GEdgar, I am too careless, missed the definition in the same page.